# Kotlin: why a function can't be stored in a variable?

Tags: lambda, kotlin, functional-programming, jvm

Why do i have to use function reference to store a function into a variable:

```
fun someFunction(i: Int): Unit = println(i)
val funVal = someFunction  // Compile error!
val funVal2 = ::someFunction // Function reference works fine
```

But I can store lambda in a variable directly:

```
val someLambda: (Int) -> Unit = { i: Int -> println(i) }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is about correct syntax. Or more precisely, about the ability of the compiler to *understand* what you are trying to tell it!

When you look at your different examples, you can find that the accepted cases use specific chars, like the colon for example. That makes it simply easier to deduct what the code is meant to say.

So, one possible reason could be a trade off. Sure, when you have

```
val a = b
```

you could allow b to be a method reference. But what if you wanted to call b() instead?! The "lexicographic" distance between b and b() is pretty small!

So to not allow for that syntax makes it a) easier to parse code, and b) harder for you to have small typos change the meaning of your code!

Comment: While an accepted answer I can't help but think it's looking for excuses to justify this.  There are no brackets. It's quite evident that the omission of () means its a reference to the function and not an invocation. I see this a lot in Kotlin - specifcally with regards to multiple assignemtns and the ternary opererator used frequently with no issue in many other languages.

Comment: It's not a correct justification. All great modern languages don't admit this confusion between function ref and function execution (event if the confusion exists in Scala.)

Comment: So you are saying "the compilers dont admit this confusion", but you are also saying that my justification that boils down to "it is confusing (and easy to get wrong)" is incorrect?

Comment: At least two languages I've programmed in, Pascal and Algol 68 (back in the days when my hair wasn't grey), allow you to call a no-arg function without parentheses, _and_ also to pass a no-arg function as a parameter to another function without using any special syntax, just by specifying its name. I have never been confused by this.

Answer (score 4):

Because `fun someFunction(i: Int): Unit = println(i)` despite being a `function` is a more concrete type called `method`, that's why you need the method reference syntax. Something [similar](http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.com/2009/05/scala-functions-vs-methods.html) happens in `Scala` too

**Example**

```
fun method(value: String) = println(value)
val function: (String) -> Unit = { value -> println(value) }

val methodRef = ::method
val functionRef = function
```

**Further reading** "Kotlin programmer dictionary"

- [Function vs Method vs Procedure](https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/kotlin-programmer-dictionary-function-vs-method-vs-procedure-c0216642ee87)
- [Function Type vs Function literal vs Lambda expression vs Anonymous function](https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/kotlin-programmer-dictionary-function-type-vs-function-literal-vs-lambda-expression-vs-anonymous-edc97e8873e)

Comment: The first reference you mention above says: "Definitely all top-level functions are not methods.". Yet, a top-level function still requires the `::functionName` syntax with the double colons.

Answer (score 4):

The [GhostCat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53796728/2196460) is quite correct, but it's missing an important point, which I think should be mentioned to make it complete.

The callable references syntax is uniform across functions and properties, but in case of properties, it is absolutely necessary to distinguish the property access `foo` from its callable reference `::foo`.

```
val foo: Int = TODO()
val fooValue = foo
val fooReference = ::foo
```

So, while functions in fact *could* get callable reference syntax with just the function name `foo` (it is not ambiguous with the function call `foo()` in any way), for uniformity, functions share the callable reference syntax `::foo` with properties, which in turn needed some special syntactic form of callable references.